# How does NSJSONSerializer determine the encoding of the given data?

Tags: ios, json, swift, foundation

I'm using NSJSONSerializer to parse some json formatted data. The data contains some 'ü' and 'ö' and such. 
I find that it does return nil, when not beforehand converting the NSData to a NSString with NSASCIIStringEncoding and reconverting it back to NSData, so that 'ü' is converted to u and so on. 
The original format of the Data is ISO-8859-1.
How ca i possibly advise the json parser to use this encoding?

Comment: Doesn't help you much, but if it isn't unicode, it isn't JSON: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt

Comment: JSON is, by definition, encoded as UTF8 if it's in byte string form.

Comment: Your best bet is to go back to wherever the ISO-8859-1 encoding is being set and see if you can change it.

Comment: @HotLicks: "JSON is, by definition, encoded as UTF8 if it's in byte string form." No. JSON just maps data structures to a character string. That character string can be encoded with different encodings, like UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.

Comment: @newacct -- I said "if it's in byte string form".

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, if it's in byte string form, it can also be UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Comment: @newacct - Perhaps I should have said "C string form".  If one simply says "string form", of course, you bump into Objective-C and Java strings which are UTF-32 and 16.

Comment: @HotLicks: It has nothing to do with Objective-C or Java strings. A byte string is just an array of bytes. It has nothing to do with language.

Comment: @newacct - A "string" is not simply an "array of bytes".  It is a sequence of characters.  And different languages have different internal representations of such strings.

Comment: @HotLicks: A "character string" is a sequence of characters. A "byte string" is a sequence of bytes. A sequence of bytes is what we've been talking about the whole time. A sequence of bytes is the only thing that has an "encoding".

Comment: "Byte string" is meaningless unless it contains characters, since a "string", in virtually all programming contexts, is a sequence of character values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159):

> **8.1.  Character Encoding**
>
> JSON text SHALL be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32.

So if your data is encoded in ISO-8859-1 then **it is not valid JSON**.

Use `NSString` to convert it to one of the defined acceptable JSON forms:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dat encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSData *utf8Data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// ... give utf8Data to NSJSONSerializer
```